# Likelihood that a bit-flip error in RAM during compilation would cause bugs in the resultant binary?

Tags: compiler-errors, hardware, ram

Suppose I'm compiling an iOS binary in Xcode on a MacBook Pro (which does not have ECC RAM), and a random bit-flip error occurs in the memory space allocated to the compile job, including compiler memory itself and the memory containing assets such as source code.

What is the most likely outcome? Is it likely that the resulting binary will contain a bug directly related to the bit flip? Or will the compile job most likely just abort with an error?

The motivation behind this question is that I'm trying to decide between ECC and non-ECC RAM for my next developer workstation.